# Atomically insert or update entity based on previous value

Tags: java, jpa

I collect some day statistics about my system, let's say, number of people using my system and total time they spent this day. My stats entity looks like this:

```
class Stats {
    Date date;
    Long numUsers; 
    Long totalTime;        
}
```

During the day I need to **update** these statistics **based on previous values**, e.g.:

```
stats.numUsers += 1;
stats.totalTime += timeSpentByLastUser;
```

Of course, if this is the first time for today, I need to **initialize** these data:

```
stats.numUsers = 1;
stats.totalTime = timSpentByFirstUserForToday;
```

Now I want to **move it all to the database**. That is, make `Stats` an entity and make atomic inserts/updates based on previous value. So how do I do this? I'm using **JPA**, so any solution fitting its model will be suitable.

Note, that JPA has mechanism for insert or update - `EntityManager.merge()` - but it doesn't take into account previous state of the entity, which is essential here.

Comment: If you DB is ACID then transactions are already atomic, all you need to do is [lock the data](http://city81.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/pessimistic-and-optimistic-locking-in.html).

Comment: Currently we use 2 databases that hold ACID properties, however it may change, so I'm looking for a solution based on JPA (I assume JPA doesn't guarantee that underlying database always holds ACID).

Comment: @ffriend Did you got an answer on your question?

Comment: @LaurentGrégoire doesn't answer below solve this issue for you? I haven't worked with JPA for years, but locking seems the most promising solution.

Comment: One proper solution involves using UPSERTS. I'm not sure the answer using locking below is correct, as sometimes the employee would not exist in the database (hence the question: inserting OR updating).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes , you maintain atomicity , by forcing the transaction locking  mechanism used for persistence.

**Example**

```
Employee employee = entityManager.find(Employee.class, id);
employee.getAddress().setCity("Ottawa");
entityManager.lock(employee, LockModeType.WRITE);
```

Refer the below link , which provides the available Lock modes in JPA 2.0

[JPA 2.0 Locking](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Locking#JPA_2.0_Locking)